# Linking c++ object fie to c object file

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++

Suppose if i have a c++ file and c file. Created object files for both of them. Now i need to link both into one executable. While i'm trying it is giving errors about c++. Can anyone help me about that.

Comment: No, not if you provide no information.

Comment: I am using **gcc & g++**. I have a cpp file, which contains some stl functionalities also. Now i like to use this **CPP** functions in another **C** project. How to do that. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this page: http://dsc.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html

Article
Mixing C and C++ Code in the Same Program

Here you will find all needed info like:

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include "header.h"
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
```

and so long ...

Answer (score 3):

To start with, all functions in the C++ file that are called from the C file has to be marked `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" int some_function();
```

This tells the C++ compiler not [*mangle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) the name.

To continue, from the C source you can of course not use any C++ features, like classes, namespaces, references, and other C++ specific functionality.

Comment: I have used STL lbraries in my program. Because of this, it is giving lot of bugs, So how to do linkage now.? **test.c**           '#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void test()
{
        vector <int>a;
        a.push_back(100);
}
'

Comment: @Kranthi Calling the function `test` from a C source file is okay, and it can contain as many C++ specific things as needed (since it's compiled by a C++ compiler).